# Should we use both the nominal variables and their derived dummy variables in ML models for prediction

Tags: machine-learning

I saw someone creating dummy variables from nominal variables for machine learning models for classification problems. And then use both the original nominal variables and the newly created dummy variables in decision tree, SVM, NN models.

I don't see the point of it. I feel the use of nominal variables with their derived dummy variables is redundant.

Am I correct or is it necessary to use both the original nominal variable and their dummy indicators?

Comment: Linear regression yes, but what about ML methods? Using both the nominal field and their derived dummy variables for classification?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of model you're training.  Simple models (such as linear ones) can be too "dumb" to "see" how the derived features relate to the original ones.

In the linear regression case, introducing a new feature that is the square of another is enough to "trick" the model; it can only "see" linear relationships, so the quadratic one looks independent.